# Error al compilar con Mysticial / Mini-Pi

Tags: c++

Estoy intentando compilar unos programas con [Mini-Pi](https://github.com/Mysticial/Mini-Pi).

Hasta ahora he podido compilar todos menos `mini-pi_optimized_3_OpenMP.cpp`

Según entiendo en GNU/Linux (Ubuntu), en la terminal escribes:

```
$ mpicxx mini-pi_optimized_3_OpenMP.cpp -o mini-pi_optimized_3_OpenMP -lm
```

Errores que me salen:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------
mini-pi_optimized_3_OpenMP.cpp: In member function ‘Mini_Pi::BigFloat Mini_Pi::BigFloat::mul(const Mini_Pi::BigFloat&, size_t, int) const’:
mini-pi_optimized_3_OpenMP.cpp:937:53: warning: ignoring attributes on template argument ‘__m128d [] {aka __vector(2) double []}’ [-Wignored-attributes]
     auto Ta = std::unique_ptr<__m128d[], SIMD_delete>((__m128d*)_mm_malloc(length * sizeof(__m128d), 16), deletor);
                                                     ^
mini-pi_optimized_3_OpenMP.cpp:938:53: warning: ignoring attributes on template argument ‘__m128d [] {aka __vector(2) double []}’ [-Wignored-attributes]
     auto Tb = std::unique_ptr<__m128d[], SIMD_delete>((__m128d*)_mm_malloc(length * sizeof(__m128d), 16), deletor);
                                                     ^
In file included from mini-pi_optimized_3_OpenMP.cpp:51:0:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/include/pmmintrin.h: In function ‘void Mini_Pi::fft_pointwise(__m128d*, __m128d*, int)’:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/include/pmmintrin.h:80:1: error: inlining failed in call to always_inline ‘__m128d _mm_addsub_pd(__m128d, __m128d)’: target specific option mismatch
 _mm_addsub_pd (__m128d __X, __m128d __Y)
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
mini-pi_optimized_3_OpenMP.cpp:299:29: note: called from here
         T[c] = _mm_addsub_pd(c0, d0);
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~
In file included from mini-pi_optimized_3_OpenMP.cpp:51:0:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/include/pmmintrin.h:80:1: error: inlining failed in call to always_inline ‘__m128d _mm_addsub_pd(__m128d, __m128d)’: target specific option mismatch
 _mm_addsub_pd (__m128d __X, __m128d __Y)
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
mini-pi_optimized_3_OpenMP.cpp:299:29: note: called from here
         T[c] = _mm_addsub_pd(c0, d0);
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Cuando busco en Internet sobre estos errores me manda a una página de Microsoft
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/68ah4xc7.aspx

¿Qué hacer? No quiero usar ni Windows ni Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Hay que aplicar dos optimizaciones usando *g++*:

- Una para *OpenMP* con `fopenmp`
- y otra para *SSE3* con `msse3`

```
g++ -fopenmp -msse3 mini-pi_optimized_3_OpenMP.cpp -o mpi-omp.exe
```

Salida del programa ejecutando `./mpi-omp.exe`:

> Computing e...
> Algorithm: Taylor Series of exp(1)
>
> Summing Series... 205026 terms
> Time: 17.6543
> Division...
> Time: 6.1657
> Total Time = 23.82
>
> Computing Pi...
> Algorithm: Chudnovsky Formula
>
> Summing Series... 70515 terms
> Time: 59.965
> Division...
> Time: 5.91046
> InvSqrt...
> Time: 6.36888
> Final Multiply...
> Time: 1.72379
> Total Time = 73.9681